# Find 2nd order polynomial with given 4th order and 2nd order polynomials (i.e. find short period with phugoid and longitudinal CEs given)

Tags: polynomials

I have a question where the characteristic equation (CE) for the longitudinal motion of an aircraft is given as (4th order polynomial):

$$\lambda^4+6.335\lambda^3+20.496\lambda^2+0.8663\lambda+0.5063=0$$
Of which within it are 2 2nd order polynomials (a short period and a phugoid CE), one of which is also given to be:

$$\approx\lambda^2+0.0346\lambda+0.02497=0$$
And so to find the other 2nd order polynomial, which the form is known as:

$$\lambda^2+a\lambda+b=0$$
Hence:

$$\lambda^4+6.335\lambda^3+20.496\lambda^2+0.8663\lambda+0.5063=(\lambda^2+0.0346\lambda+0.02497)(\lambda^2+a\lambda+b)$$

Of which I had managed to get to:

$$\lambda^4+\lambda^3(a+0.0346)+\lambda^2(b+0.0346a+0.02497)+\lambda(0.0346b+0.02497a)+0.02497b=0$$

Through comparison:
$$6.335\lambda^3=\lambda^3(a+0.0346)$$
$$20.496\lambda^2=\lambda^2(b+0.0346a+0.02497)$$
$$0.8663\lambda=\lambda(0.0346b+0.02497a)$$
$$0.5063=0.02497b$$

I can find $b$ to be (also given as the answer):

$$b=\frac{0.5063}{0.02497}\approx20.276$$

But how do I find $a$ from the above equation through substitution and comparison when its all over the place with different values? The answer I was given was:
$$a\approx6.616$$

I do not know what I am missing here or what assumptions I need to make.